# Django FormView manually set session data lost after redirect

Tags: django, session, django-3.1

I am using FormView to get some input from the user. I then try to set some of that data into the session to be used after the form validates and the user is redirected. The data is however lost.

The view:

```
    class SomeFormView(FormView):
        template_name = 'something.html'
        form_class = SomeForm

        def form_valid(self, form):
            self.request.session['some_key'] = 'some value'

            # According to manual, this should work
            self.request.session.modified = True

            # Hail Mary
            self.request.session.save()

            return super().form_valid(form)
```

If I look at the `self.request.session` contents prior to the redirect, it will have the value I've set as: `'_session_cache': {'some_key': 'some_value'}`

But when I arrive at the redirect, the data is nowhere to be found.  I tested this on Django 3.1.1 and Django 2.2.16, with both acting the same

Comment: Having the same situation right now with django 2.2.17

Comment: i am also facing this problem did you found any solution?